# Does a bounded norm of a function in L2 mean the function is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

In $L^2$ space, if the norm of a function $||f||$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ does that mean the function is bounded?

If so, why? Is there a theorem? Or a counter example?

Comment: In general, an integral bound on a function cannot give a pointwise bound. It is enough to remark that there are unbounded functions with bounded integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the function
$$
 f(x) := \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^{1/4}} & \text{if } x \in (0,1],\\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $f$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$. However,
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert f \right\Vert_{L^2}^2 = \int_0^1 |f|^2\,\mathrm{d}m = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x = 2.
\end{align*}
Moreover, as pointed out in the comments, the $L^2$-norm does not give you much information on the pointwise values of a function. Indeed, by the very nature of the Lebesgue integral, changing the values of $f$ on a null set would not affect the value of the integral.

Comment: Isn't the norm in $L^2=\sqrt{x^2}$? If I am wrong... please tell me why, it would really help me.

Comment: The $L^2([0,1])$-norm of a function $f$ is $\left( \int_0^1 |f|^2 \right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Can you tell me why? Where can I read that this is the case? When I look up Lp space it tells me the norm $||X||_p$ is $\sqrt{x^p}$

Comment: A norm has to return a real number not a function. In fact, since elements of $L^2$ aren't well defined pointwise, your "norm" would not be well defined. Which source are you referring to?

Comment: For $1 \leq p < \infty$, the norm on $L^p(X)$ is simply the map $$ f \mapsto \left( \int_X |f|^p\,\mathrm{d}m\right)^{1/p}.$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I see it. 
If you have a second, could you also please tell me then, what about C[0,1] ? I am supposed to prove a function is bounded on C[0,1] with "sup norm"
What is the norm on this C space?  (This stuff is not a pre-req to the course I'm taking -_-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91278/discussion-between-rolandcyp-and-frank).